# AndroidStudio gradle sync : failed to resolve

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have new clear android app. I want to add **volley** to my app to make HTTP request. I am developing app with Android studio using Gradle. Here is screenshot for my app:
[image]

Ass you see i am going to add volley to my app adding this line of code ***com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0*** to build.gradle file

I tried to add Retrofit too. But it gives same type of error: Failed to resolve: bla bla bla.

So i think in my situation gradle can not sync any other library different than com.android......

And i have tried add this lines of code to my build.gradle too. but nothing is changing

```
 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Please advise

Edit: After comments added build.gradle files for project and for module.
**Project:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Module:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "domain.testgradle"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```

Comment: try adding the library like this `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: @AtifFarrukh,  i tried it, but not success. And same time i have tested with this way: compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.*', no success too

Comment: post your build.gradle file here.

Comment: @AEMLoviji Can you post your build.gradle

Answer (score 2):

Volley is now published by the Android Open Source Project on jCenter:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: I added this but same error, Failed to resolve com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0

Comment: Make sure you have `jcenter()` in your repositories

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1
```

Or its latest version (Not aar)

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
```

And set

```
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

and use

```
'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
```

Comment: it worked, but now i can not add this one  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'

Comment: @AEMLoviji Use 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3' instead of yours

Comment: @AEMLoviji Glad to hear that .Let me inform about gson

Comment: i have created new question for this problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32867144/android-studio-gradle-not-recognise-com-google-code-gsongson2-3-1

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
}
```