# AndroidStudio can't find Volley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I cloned volley from git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley and imported it as a new module in AndroidStudio, but I get the following error when syncing:

> Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley.1.0.0

My build.gradle, in my app folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cs169_au.volleytest1"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps:google-maps-services:0.1.7'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley.1.0.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Add Volley Jar file, or else try to add dependency from Project Structure->Dependency-> search for Volley library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859819/androidstudio-gradle-sync-failed-to-resolve

Comment: There is no need for you to clone the repository and add it as a new module. Once you add the line compile 'com.android.volley:volley.1.0.0', Android studio will do everything for you. It will download the library and integrate it into your project. That is all I did and it worked on the first try. In fact if you integrated the repository into the module and also have the line compile 'com.android.volley:volley.1.0.0', you will get conflicts, so make sure to remove it.

Answer (score 7):

Google's official Volley is hosted in JCenter, so you have to add `jcenter()` to `repositories` in the project's **build.gradle**:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter() // Add this line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Weird that Google doesn't mention that on their website.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

`compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: Getting a "Error:Execution failed for task ':volley:processDebugResources'.
> aapt is missing" now.

Comment: Why did you edit this? Please see that the question **is** using the official verison

Comment: This answer makes no sense, the person is trying to use the Volley version from the official Google repository, this is just modifying it to get it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley.1.0.0

Open **build.gradle** and add volley support
compile `'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'` under **dependencies** section.

**Finally**

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'//1.0.19
}
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Sync`** Your Project .

**Edit**

### Using SNAPSHOT

add this to repositories section in build.gradle

```
repositories {
        maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
```

add this to dependencies section in `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19-SNAPSHOT'
```

Courtesy goes to

> https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley

Comment: So this worked for a second, but cleaning-rebuilding-syncing a second time broke it. I get a "Error:Execution failed for task  :volley:processDebugResources'. > aapt is missing" while cleaning. Same thing happens if I rebuild or sync instead.

Comment: Ah, the first time it ran on my device without errors but still gave me errors when I cleaned-rebuilt-synced.

Comment: @CCS add `multiDexEnabled true` in your `defaultConfig` section

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley.1.0.0

in android studio go to **File->project structure-> modules->app-> dependencies**
click icon **`+`** in right corner then go to module dependency select Volley.
if there is another dependencies name with volley remove that.

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 1):

It is **compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'**

and not *compile 'com.android.volley:volley.1.0.0'*

Instead of a dot use a colon.

Answer (score 1):

I also suffered with the same problem and finally resolved the following way

we should specify the maven urls in the  project level "build.gradle" file.  Then it resolved for me

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven { url 'http://jcenter.bintray.com' }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your dependencies orders or change buildToolsVersion to 24.0.3.

and then refresh.

Answer (score 0):

In android studio **go to File-> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" -> Press "Invalidate Restart" button.**

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
compile 'eu.the4thfloor.volley:com.android.volley:2015.05.28'
```

Comment: add some comment to your answer before try this, because your answer was flagged as low quality for its shortness