# Failed to resolve issue in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio for android development in a company and here when i am adding any dependency using gradle i am getting "Failed to resolve" error on every gradle dependancy.Please suggest me what is the issue behind this.

Thank you.

> Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0 Show
>   in File
> Show in
>   Project Structure dialog

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "calkinsmedia.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

This is my project level build.gradle :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: post logcat with `build.gradle`

Comment: Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0
<a href="openFile:C:/Users/bhaskar/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>

Comment: Edit your question with what @IntelliJAmiya asked

Comment: @DkThakur add `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

Comment: @DkThakur post your `build.gradle` also .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have already added it.

Comment: @DkThakur No . You did't post your `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i have edit it please check

Comment: Make sure you have added `jcenter()` in your repositories

Comment: @ThomasRoulin I have added it also in my repositories

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/35933791/3395198

Comment: Also, update your  buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" to buildToolsVersion "25.1.1", and your appcompat as well

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya you are suggesting me this link for volley,volley is just an example its happening with all other also

Comment: call `compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I have done this also but getting same issue yet

Comment: @DkThakur okay .Could you share project level `build.gradle`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Please check my edited question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I found the solution.What was the issue,in my system there is a antivirus which preventing the android studio to download dependencies.Once I have turn off the antivirus all working fine.